# Kitware VTK Activiz.NET InvalidCastException when instantiating vtkCommand child

Tags: c#, .net, vtk

I have a working C++ program with VTK that I'm trying to rewrite in C#. I installed the following Nuget packet :

```
PM> Install-Package Activiz.NET.x86
```

Nothing worked with the 64bits version, I don't understood why, so I tried installing the 32bits version, and it seems a bit better... But still, I have a problem :

With this simple class inheriting from vtkCommand:

```
class VtkBoxCallback : vtkCommand
{
    public VtkBoxCallback() {}
}
```

When I do :

```
VtkBoxCallback l_callback = new VtkBoxCallback();
```

I get the following exception :

```
unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in Kitware.VTK.dll

specified cast is not valid
```

any idea why?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem when trying to implement an animation using the Subject/Observer and Command design pattern that is used in vtk (C++). I guess the problem is related with the fact that vtkCommand is a wrapped class. Instead of trying to use the same pattern, I used events which were added on Activiz. 
In other words, instead of doing this:

```
public class MyCommandClass : vtkCommand
{
    public MyCommandClass() { }

    public override void Execute(vtkObject caller, uint eventId, IntPtr callData)
    {
         //My callback code
    }
}
```

and this:

```
vtkClass myObservedObject = new vtkClass();
MyCommandClass myCommandObject = new MyCommandClass();
myObservedObject.AddObserver((uint)vtkCommand.EventIds.Event, myCommandObject, 1f);
```

I did this:

```
vtkClass myObservedObject = new vtkClass();
myObservedObject.Event += MyCallback;
```

and this:

```
void MyCallback(vtkObject sender, vtkObjectEventArgs e)
{
    //My callback code
}
```